# Google+ share image using URL like Facebook

Tags: android, facebook, google-plus, universal-image-loader

I'm currently looking for a way to share in Google+ using URL from web and not from local storage. Problem is that I've used [UniversalImageLoader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader) to cache my image and I don't have the image file of the images I wanted to post on my share. I wanted it to be as simple the way facebook done their sharing but using the `setContentUrl(Uri.parse(IMG_URL))` will give me the way I wanted it minus the image URL below the post.

Other workarounds I'm thinking is to download the image using the URL, store it somewhere on the device then share it using the `setStream(Uri.parse(IMG_URI))` but only problem is that I will need to wait more compared to sharing using URL.

Now is there's any way I can achieve a faster image sharing on Google+? Or if ever is there's a way I can convert the cached file back into image so that I can share it using Stream?

Comment: I haven't used UniversalImageLoader in over a year but you can get the File from the disk cache. 

See: https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader/blob/master/library/src/com/nostra13/universalimageloader/utils/DiskCacheUtils.java#L34-38

Comment: Yes I tried it and it gives me this result: /data/data/com.test.kahel.mobile/cache/-510492220 now I'm not sure if this is a cached file or an image file. and since I can't upload it on google if it is not in valid file format.

Comment: Okay, now I'm sure that this is not in image format and it can't be attached on the share post. what I tried is to add it as url itself and add url with file extension concat on end. both didn't work. I wonder if I can covert it back into image format before upload?